# How can I define a facade in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, lumen, laravel-facade

I had a Laravel project and I've added the following line in `config/app.php` file (`aliases` section).

```
'Telegram'  => Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram::class
```

And then it was working:

```
use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;
```

---

Now I've migrated to Lumen micro framework. How can I do the same thing in Lumen?

Noted that I've added the following line in `boostrap/app.php` file (and `$app->withFecade` is uncommented now)

```
class_alias('Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram::class', 'Telegram');
```

But still it is unknown and `php artisan vendor publish` command throws:

```
Class 'Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram::class' not found
```

Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186418/1046387 alternatively you may need to re-run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: If you do `use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram` you don't really need to set an alias in either framework

Answer (score 2):

You should use either:

```
class_alias(Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram::class, 'Telegram');
```

(here it can be imported)

or

```
class_alias('Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram', 'Telegram');
```